# Insert into table does not work with select left join

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I am trying to insert new records from openrowset query into existing table that do not exist in the table. 
Here's the code:

```
insert into SRC_TABLE
REP.ID
,REP.COLUMN1
from openrowset (blabla) REP
left join SRC_TABLE TAB on REP.ID = TAB.ID
where TAB.ID is null
```

I get the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'REP'.
```

However when I run the query as follows:

```
select
REP.ID
,REP.COLUMN1
from openrowset (blabla) REP
left join SRC_TABLE TAB on REP.ID = TAB.ID
where TAB.ID is null
```

works as expected giving me the rows that don't exist in the SRC_TABLE.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
insert into table (ID, Column)
select
REP.ID
,REP.COLUMN1
from openrowset (blabla) REP
left join SRC_TABLE TAB on REP.ID = TAB.ID
where TAB.ID is null
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Besides that, the report and table columns are matched.

Comment: OK, I got a little confused but after a while I figured out why it is not working. Of course the insert into must be followed by select... In my case was not.

Comment: ... so it does work? If you find yourself typing 'doesn't work' you should stop and explain in detail and most of the time you solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 (...)
SELECT cte.DepartmentID
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=SQL_2012;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'SELECT DepartmentID FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department') cte
LEFT JOIN AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department t ON cte.DepartmentID = t.DepartmentID
```

Comment: There is no insert here so it won't do much